# Vimeo API to fetch video with vanity url?

Tags: api, vimeo

Does anybody know how to get a response from Vimeo's api for vanity / custom urls like the following:

http://vimeo.com/jarominne/regarde-moi or http://vimeo.com/davidfield/caterpillar

The standard Api request for a video id doesn't work.

**Does not work:** https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/regarde-moi.json

**Works:** https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/58086788.json

I don't see anything that makes sense or is a clear cut solution in their docs. I don't care about language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, this is a crappy php solution I just quickly thought of shortly after asking this question.

Improvements very welcome!

Essentially, if we do not have a video id (a numeric value), assume our id is a video title. Fetch our user data with the username from the url and grab all their videos. Loop through those videos and try and match the title with our "video id" (which in the case above is really the video title).

** assumes $this->id = your video id or video username
** assumes $this->user = your vimeo username

```
public $apis = array(
    'vimeo_image' => 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/%s.json',
    'vimeo_user' => 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/user/%s/videos.json'
);

public function vimeoThumbnail($size = 'small')
{
    if(preg_match('/[0-9]+/', $this->id)) {
        $video_id = $this->id;
    } else {
        $videos = file_get_contents(sprintf($this->apis['vimeo_user'], $this->video->user));
        if($videos !== false) {
            $videos = json_decode($videos);
            foreach($videos as $video) {
                if(stristr($video->title, $this->id)) {
                    $video_id = $video->id;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $contents = file_get_contents(sprintf($this->apis['vimeo_image'], $video_id));

    if($contents !== false) {
        $contents = json_decode($contents);

        if(is_array($contents)) $contents = array_shift($contents);
        if(!is_object($contents)) return false;

        $image_url = $contents->{'thumbnail_' . $size};

        return $image_url;
    }

    return false;
}
```